# Releasing canvas after drawing on TextureView

Tags: android, canvas, textureview

How do I free up memory after drawing on a `TextureView` with `Canvas`. How releasing the `Canvas` after drawing.

I tried unlocking the canvas after drawing with

```
    mTextureView.unlockCanvasAndPost (canvas);
```

But in the logcat I get an "already in use " error. Which means that the Texture View is still using the canvas and has not released the canvas.

Comment: Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.